# How to add spacing before first line of paragraph in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, spacing, paragraph

I'm trying to add spacing before one paragraph in word document that is being automatically generated. I only need spacing before first line of that particular paragraph. Problem is in next line after first blank line.

```
With Wapp
    With .Selection
        .TypeParagraph
        'Add line spacing
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .TypeText St1
        .TypeParagraph

        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 36
        .BoldRun
        'Centers text
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
        .TypeText St2
        .BoldRun
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0

        .TypeText VBA.vbNewLine
        .TypeText St3
        .TypeText VBA.vbNewLine
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
    End With
End With
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Can you show us a section of the document where the problem appears?

Comment: https://failiem.lv/u/75wymqr9 before bold text I want more free space, but not additional blank line

Comment: You need to show paragaph marking for us to understand the image you posted.  However I suspect you have an extraneous TypeParagraph.  Try using F* to step through the code whilst the document is displayed to see where the mistake is.

Comment: To use Word optimally, this kind of formatting should be part of a *style*. Define styles for the formatting required in the document, then apply them as needed. That will make for much more compact and faster code and reduce problems with memory issues. If the formatting later needs to be adjusted, it's simply a matter of changing the style definition - the formatting will then adjust throughout the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapped two lines of code

```
.TypeText VBA.vbNewLine
```

and

```
.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
```

Seems that it is important to place .ParagraphFormat after .TypeParagraph or VBA.vbNewLine then it started to work as I wanted.

```
With Wapp
    With .Selection
        .TypeParagraph
        'Add line spacing
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .TypeText St1
        .TypeParagraph
        'Starts spacing
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
        .BoldRun
        'Centers text
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
        .TypeText St2
        .BoldRun
        .TypeText VBA.vbNewLine
        'Ends spacing
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        .TypeText St3
        .TypeText VBA.vbNewLine
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following line to create first line indent of 1 inch (72 points) for the current paragraph:

```
.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
```

Comment: Indentation is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Oh... I might not understand it well. can the screenshot of desired output be shared. It will help to solve the specific problem.

Comment: Look at the Answer posted by the person who asked the question to understand what was wanted (different spacing *between* paragraphs).